# UIButton won't go to highlighted state

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

When you tap a button it should go into its highlighted state right? Kind of darkening the texture automatically to give it the press effect. The problem I have is that this is working nice, but only after I drag inside the button, or on some buttons, when I hold the click for a while. If I tap it fast, it does the function hooked to it, but it doesn't go into highlighted state, or it does but it doesn't show. This is really irritating because it makes it look like the button is not pressed when it really is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: 
i found the problem, it was due to having a swipe drag gesture receiver in that view, after removing it it worked like a charm!

Comment: Is your UIButton embedded inside a UIScrollView (or subclass like a UITableView)?

Comment: yes and no, in some cases it is in scrollview, in some it is not.
edit: i noticed that it does work fine on my root uiviewcontroller where it is not in the scrollview! is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something further up the view hierarchy will be interfering with your tap gesture.

For `UIButton`s embedded in a `UIScrollView`, the scroll view purposely delays touches in order to differentiate a user's pan gesture (scroll) from a tap (which it will pass through to it's subviews).

You can eliminate this delay by setting the`delaysContentTouches` property on the scroll view to `NO`, either in code or via the Scroll View > Touches section in the IB/ Storyboard inspector. However, doing so means the user won't be able to scroll if they start the pan gesture with their finger on the button, so it's generally not recommended.

Comment: what about those buttons that are not in the scrollview? if it helps ,my buttons use custom image rather than text only. but i dun understand why they would work in one uiviewcontroller and not in the other, if none is in the scrollview

Comment: The issue is likely to be interference from further up the view hierarchy, not your view controller(s). I took from your comments above that the problem only occurs when your buttons are embedded in a scroll view? If this is not the case, please post some code demonstrating the problem so we can investigate more thoroughly.

Comment: i edited my first post, i found the problem and this helped me locate it, it wasn't scrollview but gesture receiver! thanks a lot!